# Force A UIWebView Page to Press A Link?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, stringbyevaluatingjavascr

Hello I have wrote an app that gets recent player information from xbox live and shows the players you are playing with in a game!  I am trying to improve the app by having no need for the user to be on the web page and just gets the list of recent players.  Unfortunately I am stuck thats why i am here!

Here is the issue when you log on to the xbox live site there is no link that just loads the page with the data on it.  You have to physically press the link on the page which i believe is running a java script that gets the list of players.   This is what the link code looks like, `<a href="#recentPlayers" class="loadsRecent"> " Players you Met"</a>`

I beleive this is the script that is run when the link is pressed, 
`<h2>Players You Met (<span>${players.length}</span>)</h2>
        {{if players.length}}
            <ol>
            {{each players}}
                <li data-gamertag="${$value.GamerTag}">{{tmpl($value) "#unknownPlayerTmpl"}}                </li>
            {{/each}}
            </ol>
        {{else}}
            <div class="none">No players recently met</div>
        {{/if}}`

Unfortunately adding #recentplayers to the url does not solve the issue.  Also i have tried looking for an API that would just give me the information but can not find one.

So ultimately if possible i want to have a web page load and either force that script to run or simulate the link being pressed without the user having to do it.  Thanks for any help!

If anyone wants to see a demo of the app so far i have a video on youtube so you could possibly get a better idea of what I mean.[YouTube Video of App](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QrUDgK-9NMQ)

Comment: Just as a notice, do you plan on uploading this app to the AppStore? 9 out of 10 that the AppStore review team would block it, but that's only my opinion ;)

Comment: it is already on the app store!  why do you think they would have rejected it tho?

Comment: They usually reject apps that work with UIWebView as the main interface. But you never know, though

Comment: interesting i did not know that i guess i got lucky in the acceptance!  It goes to a tableview and has an in depth stat page when you click on the player in the table view.